# UIPrintPageRenderer paper size not changing

Tags: swift, uiprintpagerenderer

I am trying to convert some HTML into a PDF document to save on my back end. However, I am unable to set the paper size of the print renderer. The paper size always remains A4 even when I change the 'paperRect' - I need the paper size to be A6. Any ideas?

```
let pageFrame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 595.2, height: 600)

// Set the page frame.
self.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: pageFrame), forKey: "paperRect")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [UIGraphicsPDFRenderer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigraphicspdfrenderer#2863995) instead of `UIPrintPageRenderer`. You can make pages with custom sizes, using the function [beginPage(withBounds:pageInfo:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigraphicspdfrenderercontext/1649126-beginpage)

```
let pdf = renderer.pdfData { (context) in
    context.beginPage(withBounds: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 595.2, height: 600), pageInfo: [:])

    drawYourHTML(on: context) // Implement this function like what you want

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it correctly by setting `paperRect`. However you may have called the default `UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()` for configuring each page, which is using default values like A4 paper size. Try using `UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(paperRect, nil)` instead since you already got `paperRect`.

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1623915-uigraphicsbeginpdfpagewithinfo